# How to make a primitive class (int) subclass INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, inotifypropertychanged

How can i make a primitive type as `int` a subclass of INotifyPropertyChanged? Can i do so without creating an additional class?

Comment: why would you want to do this?

Comment: you want to notify someone if the value of 1 changes to 2 (ints are immutable)? 
If you succeed I'd like to subscribe to that notification. It would potentially have an impact on my personal economy

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`int` is an immutable struct so the point is moot.

But no, you cannot add interfaces to a class or struct you don't own. You'd have to wrap it somehow.

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to make your own class that implements INotifyPropertyChanged and wraps the type.

A quick example would be:

```
public class ChangingPrimitive<T> : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    // ... implement INotifyPropertyChanged Here

    public T Inner {get;set;}

    // ... optional work to expose the inner type directly
}
```